# Javascript regex search until but do not include

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a problem and I cannot seem to solve it.

I have some URL's like this:

- http://www.example.com/test/filter=show
- http://www.example.com/test/filter=show/results=true

I want to remove only `\/filter=(\w+)(\/?)`, so only `filter=show` but do not include the next forward slash. Also `filter` is just a variable.

What I have tried:

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com/test/filter=show/results=true';
var param = 'filter';
var oldParam = '\/('+param+'=(.*?))';
var reg = new RegExp(oldParam, "gi");
var result = url.replace(reg, "/");
```

This removes only `filter=` and leave out show.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Be careful with the escaping. Regex built with the constructor _must_ be double escaped since it's inside a string, `\\/`. Not sure if that's the whole solution but the problem is there.

Comment: If you remove only `filter=show` you *want* the double-slash? from `'http://www.example.com/test/filter=show/results=true'` to: `'http://www.example.com/test//results=true'`?

Comment: @DavidThomas, aah, no, I want to have `http://www.example.com/test/results=true`, or `http://www.example.com/test`, depends if that parameter is set. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com/test/filter=show/results=true';
var result = url.replace(/filter=([^&\/]*[/]?)/gi, "");
alert(result);
```

================= UPDATE ==================

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com/test/filter=show/results=true';
var params = 'filter';
    params = params+'=([^&\/]*[/]?)'
var reg = new RegExp(params, "gi");
var result = url.replace(reg, "");
alert(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to make filter a variable in this case? I can't make functions for every variable I have, if I want to remove `results=true` ?

Comment: i updated for make **filter** as variable, if you want remove **results=true** , you only change **var params = 'filter';** to **var params = 'results';**

Answer (score 2):

Try look ahead like

```
'http://www.example.com/test/filter=show/results=true'.replace(/\/filter=.*?(?=\/)/, '')
```

Ex:

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com/test/filter=show/results=true';
var param = 'filter';
var oldParam = '\\/'+param+'=.*?(?=\\/)';
console.log(oldParam)
var reg = new RegExp(oldParam, "gi");
var result = url.replace(reg, "");
console.log(result)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c8YVb/)

Comment: Thank you, but how to make `filter` a variable in this case? I can't make functions for every variable I have, if I want to remove `results=true` ?

Answer (score 1):

This should suit your needs:

```js
var url = "http://www.example.com/test/filter=show/results=true";
var param = "filter";
var pattern = "/" + param + "=[^/]+";
var regex = new RegExp(pattern, "gi");
var result = url.replace(regex, "");

document.write(result);
```

Prints:

```
http://www.example.com/test/results=true
```

Explanation:

```
/filter=[^/]+
```

[image: Regular expression image]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/9k_R0pWiUCOd5dfN)